# Rails 3 routing how to match multiple?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-url

How do I match multiple controller for example an id?

I have tried this in my routes:

```
match '/:id' => 'kategoris#show'
match '/:id' => 'tags#show'
```

Comment: you can't do that :) just wondering, why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Because I have categories and tags. And I want a flat link structure

Comment: what if there is Category and tag with id = 1, so how your routes would handle this request: `/1` ?

Comment: I use has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true

Comment: And there are no duplicates names

Comment: Why didn't you write it in your question? Your question would have a sense though

Comment: Then @stef answer is what you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails controller routing isn't appropriate for you if you're wanting to match `http://example.com/<something>`.

You could create a single ThingsController:

```
match '/:id' => 'things#show'
```

and then do something appropriate in your ThingsController.

Eg. in Sinatra (which you could mount as a Rack middleware) you'd do this:

```
get "/:id" do :id
  if(@tag = Tag.find(:id))
     haml :tag
  elsif(@category = Category.find(:id))
     haml :category
  else
     pass #crucially passes on saying 'not found anything'.
  end
end
```

You're going to get a scream of anguish from the RESTful Rails envangelists either way.

Comment: Thanks! I would go for a single controller-action strategy. I didn't know I could such wonderful thing from routing :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can implement an identifiable difference in your tag id's and category id's, then you can use constraints to look them up. For example if categories always begin with a number and tags never do then you can do this.

```
match '/:id' => 'categories#show', :constraints => { :id => /^\d+/ }
match '/:id' => 'tags#show'
```

The first line would match only if `:id` begins with a digit. If that doesn't match, the second line catches the leftovers. So; `/67-something` gets routed to categories controller and `/something` gets routed to the tags controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
match 'kategoris/:id' => 'kategoris#show'
match 'tags/:id' => 'tags#show'
```

or

```
match '/:id/kategoris' => 'kategoris#show'
match '/:id/tags' => 'tags#show'
```

Comment: I want an flat link structure