# root path for multiple controllers on rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two resource controllers where I am using a slug to represent the ID. (friendly_id gem).

I am able to have the show path for one resource on the route but not for two at the same time. ie.

```
root :to => 'home#index'
match '/:id' => "properties#show"
match '/:id' => "contents#show"
```

Basically I want urls like,

```
# Content
domain.com/about-us
domain.com/terms
# Property
domain.com/unique-property-name
domain.com/another-unique-property-name
```

Whatever resource I put on top works. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advace if you can help.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786725/rails-3-routing-how-to-match-multiple

Answer (score 5):

This is untested, but try utilizing a `constraint` on your route.

```
root :to => 'home#index'
match '/:id', :to => "properties#show",
              :constraints => lambda { |r| Property.find_by_id(r.params[:id]).present? }
match '/:id', :to => "contests#show",
              :constraints => lambda { |r| Contest.find_by_id(r.params[:id]).present? }
```

Alternatively, you can create a separate class that responds to `matches?` instead of defining a `lambda` proc.  (I recommend placing these classes into separate files that will autoload within your Rails app.)

```
# app/constraints/property_constraint.rb
class PropertyConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    property = Property.find_by_id(request.params[:id])
    property.present?
  end
end

# app/constraints/contest_constraint.rb
class ContestConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    contest = Contest.find_by_id(request.params[:id])
    contest.present?
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
root :to => 'home#index'
match '/:id', :to => "properties#show", :constraints => PropertyConstraint
match '/:id', :to => "contests#show", :constraints => ContestConstraint
```

Unfortunately this results in an extra DB query (once in the routes, and once more in your controller).  If anyone has a suggestion on minimizing this, please share. :)

Answer (score 2):

This Rails Engine does what you want:

[Slug Engine at Github](https://github.com/jcarlson/slug-engine)

Basically, the author's approach was to mount a Rails Engine inside his main app. This Engine incorporates both a controller for handling slugs that exist and a piece of middleware for filtering out and abstaining on slugs that don't exist.

He explains why he took this approach and other aborted solutions in a rather detailed and interesting [blog post](http://living5to9.com/2011/11/slug-engine/). This blog post and the slug engine source code should be enough detail for you to get your own code up and running, but that open-source engine seems to be exactly what you're looking for if you want a drop-in solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a middleware

1. Detect slug in path
2. If Content with this slug exists - change request path to "contents/:id"
3. If Property with this slug exists - change request path to "properties/:id"
4. in your routing set:

   match 'contents/:id' => "properties#show"

   match 'properties/:id' => "contents#show"

Answer (score 1):

You could write another controller which takes the id from the router and checks if the id belongs to properties or content and renders the appropriate view.

```
match '/:id' => "router#show"
```

The controller would do something like this:

```
def show
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
    if @property then
        render 'property/show'
    else
        @content = Content.find(params[:id])
        render 'content/show
    end
end
```

Havn't tested this code, but this idea should work.

Comment: Thanks whistler.  This is the route I have taken but would have been nice to do it from the rack middleware I think.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do this in a more RESTful way, if possible. Basically, you have two different resources and you should separate them:

```
match 'properties/:id' => "properties#show"
match 'contents/:id'   => "contents#show"
```

This will give you many advantages down the road. One immediate benefit is that you can avoid clashes between ids for properties and content. (Note that friendly_id will not help you with inter-model slug clashes in your original scheme.)

Comment: would you still have root? below perhaps?

Comment: Yes, depending on how your app should work of course. But most likely.